# Image storage in database

Tags: android, database

Is BLOB is the only data type by which an image can be stored in database.What is the advantage of using BLOB.What about portability in BLOB datatype.Please give tutorial based on image storage.

Comment: i think you should convert image to bitmap and then convert bitmap to base64 string and save base64 string in database ...

Comment: Can you give some tutorial based on image storage.Also what about performance converting to bitmap and BLOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides storing bytes in a **Blob** typed column, another way could be to convert the bytes into `Base64` string and simply store that string in a **Text** typed column. And regarding portability, you decide which one's better and you prefer. Personally I like to play with strings rather than bytes :)

To convert image into Base64 string:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
final String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

To convert Base64 string into image:

```
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(imgString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas..Can you please give some appropriate links based on the image storage and performance and database backup.I searched for it ,but i cant appropriate link..

Comment: you shouldn't worry about performance if your images are small in size. see my updated answer for image conversion

Comment: What if the size of the image is large. Like I am using couchbase lite as my database but it stucks when I try to save large images(Base64 string of image).

Comment: For larger images, I would suggest you to look for file system rather than database, as suchbig images will unnecessarily increase the size of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the image you can store the byte array of that image in DB.You can convert that image to byte array & store in db.When u want to retrieve that image you will get the byte array from convert that byte array to bitmap, you will get your image.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/550604/Android/Mobile/Help-insert-retreive-image-database

Comment: Thanks Sumant..IS this the only two way to store the image.Also give me some details about performance of various formats..